# generate fixed no of latitude and longitude between two points

Tags: javascript, java, graph, graph-algorithm

In this scenario, I have already known lat long of source and destination and distance b/w these  is also known.

Suppose,lat long of source and destination are (x,y) and (a,b) and distance b/w these is 500 km.

Now my requirement is that I want to get lat long of 1000  point between these points at a interval of 1 Km b/w each point.

Note- **since the straight distance b/w source and destination is 500 km and points b/w source and destination is 1000  so the lat long will not be on straight line(that's my requirement).**

In the image Red and Green locators are source and destination point having straight distance 500 km. And grey dots are 1000 required latitude points on a interval of 1 Km.

[Click here to see a sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cubdu.jpg)

Comment: 1) what do you already did? 2) Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 3) And here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic to implement.

Comment: 1) I searched but did not found any hint. 2) Can you provide any geodesic program in java becease I have already read this article from wifi. So plz provide any java or javascript solution if you can

Comment: How the path should be? Is it random? It's pretty difficult to even start thinking in what you want without a precise and complete set of rules... Your problem rules are imcomplete.

Comment: @davidbuzatto, If we draw a circle with two points source and destination, then all points of path should be inside that circle.

Comment: I wrote some considerations, take a look. You have a really big (probably almost impossible) problem to solve...

Answer (score 0):

Here is your starting point:

```
/**
 * Source: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/12types/GreatCircle.java.html
 * @author David Buzatto
 */
public class SphericalDistance {

    /**
     * Calculates the spherical distance between two geographical coordinates.
     * 
     * @param lat1 The latitude of the first geographical coordinate in degrees.
     * @param lng1 The longitude of the first geographical coordinate in degrees.
     * @param lat2 The latitude of the second geographical coordinate in degrees.
     * @param lng2 The longitude of the second geographical coordinate in degrees.
     * @param degreeRatio The ratio between one degree and the metric unit. For example, one degree variation in the Earth (considering it's a sphere) corresponds to 111120 meters.
     * @return The distance between two geographical coordinates using the degreeRatio.
     */
    public static double sphericalDistance( double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2, double degreeRatio ) {

        double x1 = Math.toRadians( lat1 );
        double y1 = Math.toRadians( lng1 );
        double x2 = Math.toRadians( lat2 );
        double y2 = Math.toRadians( lng2 );

        double a = Math.pow( Math.sin( ( x2 - x1 ) / 2 ), 2 )
                + Math.cos( x1 ) * Math.cos( x2 ) * Math.pow( Math.sin( ( y2 - y1 ) / 2 ), 2 );

        double angle = 2 * Math.asin( Math.min( 1, Math.sqrt( a ) ) );
        return degreeRatio * Math.toDegrees( angle );

    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        double degreeRatio = 111120; // meters per degree
        double lat1 = -20;
        double lng1 = -50;
        double lat2 = -20;
        double lng2 = -54.7885801;

        System.out.printf( "Distance between (%f, %f) and (%f, %f): %fkm\n", 
                lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, 
                sphericalDistance( lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, degreeRatio/1000 ) );
    }

}
```

This code is an approximation, since the Earth is not an sphere, but an ellipsoid.

**EDIT**

Suppose you have a reticulated plane, covering the circle that has as limits the source and target geographical coordinates. In this example, the reticule is equaly divided in 250 lines and 250 columns to not get a too big picture. In your case you will need the double of it. Consider that each parallel line is far from the next of by the distance of 1km.

[image]

Consider this reticule as a graph. Each line cross is a graph vertex/node. The answer you want is something like: what's the path that I should choose to cross 1000 edges, coming out of from the source and reaching the target?

[image]

This answer is almost answered using the breadth first search algorithm with some modification to choose paths with some size, since you will not be able to get this exact value, because the graph structure is reticular. This algorithm will result in one of the the shortest path/jumps inside this graph, but you need to change it to achieve paths with some size. To get an better approximation you will need to build a better strucure that does not have this good behavior. In my example this is simplified because there is just 4 degrees of liberty for the edges, i.e., 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees. In your real problem, the path that interconects a pair of vertices can be rotated in 360 degres. If you enumerate each path of 1000km that exists in this graph (with 360 degrees of liberty) you will have 360^1000 possibilities! You can, of course, have something really really really enormous if your rotation can use minutes and seconds! An exact answer is almost impossible, so you will need some kind of approximation/optimization technique like the rationale that I presented to you.

You also need to consider that you are dealing with geographical coordinates, not cartezian. Now, why do you need this? I'm really curious.

Good luck, I think you will really need!!!

**EDIT 2**

As I already suspected, you have a NP-complete problem, since you need a path with an exact size. Take a look here: [How to find path of exact length in graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881014/how-to-find-path-of-exact-length-in-graph)

I will edit your question to tag it with graph-algorithm. Maybe some specialist can help you and correct some kind of missconception that I may said.